# Как обратиться к перменным $smarty из php кода

Tags: php, smarty

Есть вот такая строка

```
<input type="text" value="{$categoryID}" name="cat">
```

Можно ли как-то обратиться к переменной $categoryID из php кода?

UP

smarty.php

```
$smarty->assign( "categoryID", $categoryID);
```

cat.html

```
... код и include файла smarty.php
{php}
    $foo = $smarty->get_template_vars('$categoryID');
    print_r($foo);
{/php}
```

Comment: вы же в пхп коде ее туда закинули `$smarty->assign('categoryID, $catId)`. Или хотите извлечь и изменить ранее добавленную переменную?

Comment: @teran , да, нужно изменить ранее добавленную

Comment: попробуйте `getTemplateVars()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для получения значений ранее присвоенных переменных шаблона в **Smarty 3** используется метод [`getTemplateVars()`](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/api.get.template.vars.tpl). При вызове без параметров возвращает весь массив  присвоенных переменных, а при указании в качестве параметра имени переменной, возвращает соответственно ее значение.

```
<?php
    $smarty->assign('foo', 'bar');
    $foo = $smarty->getTemplateVars('foo');

    $all_tpl_vars = $smarty->getTemplateVars();
```

Для более ранних версий (**Smarty 2.x**) используется [`get_template_vars()`](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/ru/api.get.template.vars.tpl)

```
$smarty = new Smarty;
$smarty->assign('foo', 123);
$foo = $smarty->get_template_vars('foo');
print_r($foo);
```

**UPD**

Поскольку вопрос был обвнолен, то решение несколько меняется. Выше приведенный код относится не к шаблону, а пхп коду. В случае, доступа к переменной из шаблона внутри тэгов `{php}` код будет следующий:

```
{php}
    print_r($this->get_template_vars('foo'))
{/php}
```

Естественно тут работа идет уже внутри самого смарти, т.к. что обращаться надо к `$this`.

ну а вообще тэг `{php}` исключен из Smarty3, т.к.  не надо мешать логику и представление, ибо это плохо.

Comment: так уже пробовал   $foo = $smarty->get_template_var('categoryID');
print_r($foo);  Но в середине страницы шаблон крашится

Comment: @sbaikov а откуда у вас подчеркивания в имени функции?

Comment: голова уже кругом. На автомате начал из modx писать функцию. Попробовал сейчас $foo = $smarty->getTemplateVars('categoryID');
print_r($foo);  всё равно крашится

Comment: @sbaikov смарти какой версии 2 или 3?

Comment: версия 2.6.10 ....

Comment: @sbaikov тогда `get_template_vars()`

Comment: так и было... но всё равно не работает

Comment: @sbaikov тогда падает не из-за этого, либо вы как то криво вызываете. Если падает, то с какой ошибкой?

Comment: без ошибок, просто белый экран в этом divе

Comment: причём Ваш вариант работает, подстраиваю под себя - крашится ( сверху UP)

Comment: @sbaikov обновил ответ.