# Как извлечь счётчик массива из $smarty в php

Tags: php, smarty

Ковыряюсь со старым движком ShopScript. На странице есть цикл

```
{section name=i loop=$aux_pages}
 //код
{/section}
```

Можно ли как-то получить значение переменной i, что бы с ней работать в php коде?

Получилось пока только визуально отобразить i в инпут (в теле цикла соотв.)

```
<input type="text" value="{$smarty.section.i.index}" name="cic">
```

или может как то извлечь значение инпута без отправки формы с этим инпутом?

UPD: версия smarty 2.6.10

Comment: версию smarty напишите,  2 или 3?

Comment: в пхп коде, это  вставка тэгов `{php}` т.е. версия 2?

Comment: @teran версия 2.6.10

Comment: можете попробовать [через `get_temaplate_var()`](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/606149/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-smarty-%d0%b8%d0%b7-php-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0/606167#606167), предварительно скопировав переменную куда-либо а-ля {$x = $smarty.section.i.index}, но не факт что извлечется, т.к. вроде немного для других целей функция

Comment: @teran потестил. Да, не извлекается(

Comment: @teran после присваивания вывожу $x в инпут, но он не выводится. Может присваивание не так в smarty выполняется?

Comment: да, возможно такой синтаксис только в 3й версии появился. [Раньше было](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/ru/language.custom.functions.tpl#language.function.assign) `{assign var="x" value=....}` или `{assign "x" .... }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Огромное спасибо за пищу для размышлений [teran](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/223826/teran)

Вытащил счётчик костылями, но может кому пригодится.

```
{section name=i loop=$aux_pages}
    {if ($smarty.section.i.index >=0)}
         {assign var="a" value=$smarty.section.i.index}
    {/if}
 {php}
 $id_name = $this->get_template_vars('a'); //извлекаем переменную a
 echo $id_name;
//Тело цикла
{/section}
```